# Sharepoint 2010: How to access analytics data to create summary roll-up web parts?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, analytics, webtrends

I know there is a web analytics web part out of the box, but it isn't configurable and is limited to "most viewed" and "most searched terms".  I want to display data like "most emailed" and "recently viewed" information too.  Is there an API that exposes this data from the SharePoint 2010 analytics repository??

Many thanks!

Comment: Please see the post : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/9b454dd9-04a4-4632-b018-82f41e378eb3

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, after extensive research it appears as though Microsft has not provided an API to access the analytics data, but they are giving us the specifications (see link below) document detailing where it is stored in the database.  I gotta believe an API is forthcoming...

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/8/858F2155-D48D-4C68-9205-29460FD7698F/[MS-MOSSUAN].PDF